# Google Play beta invitation - App not available message on some device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, beta-testing, google-developers-console

I have an android game with open beta test going. However, Opt-in URL shows "App not available" on most devices I tried (my Lenovo A6000, two PC at the office, and another mobile phone I don't know the detail). Some machine (My pc, my friend's Galaxy Note 2 and his PC) works correctly. I don't know what's happening. The app supports all devices for now. Country we're in is included. Can anyone help me about this?

This is a game made by Unity, and it's already been released so I need beta test to work so I can test the feature.

I tried accepting invitation on PC, and let it download the app to my android. It did download the beta version, but Google IAP doesn't treat me or my friend as a beta tester as it actually subtracted our money. And on I got IAP error on my phone too. I opened the logcat, It's IAP Error type=3 subtype=0

Also, I'd like to clarify that I use same google account on my PC and on my phone, but one shows invitation correctly, while the says "Apps not available"

Comment: Open or closed beta?

Comment: Open beta @LunarWatcher

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem and it's driving me crazy...!